# animate object back and forth in a random movement

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i am tring to move my fish back and forth (with a flip) in a random movement

any suggestion?

```
$(".fish_wrap").animate({"left":"-90px"}, "slow");
```

here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/WabvX/5/

Comment: check out some awesome "flip" plugins here - http://www.jquery4u.com/animation/10-jquery-flip-effect-plugins/

Comment: so after you animate it to the left use the flip plugin and animate back to the original position

Comment: @Vandesh thank you, do plugins can work on fiddle?

Comment: some of them might, if you copy the entire JS source from the plugin to JS in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is flip the image using some plugin (or write your own!) and then animate it back to the original position.
Check out some cool plugins [here.](http://www.jquery4u.com/animation/10-jquery-flip-effect-plugins/)

Also, you can try some of these plugins in the fiddle by actually pasting their JS code in the fiddle's JS section (Just that you need to be aware of the dependencies of these plugins like JQuery etc.)

Comment: here i found this http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/ can u show me little bit how can i use the "right" in my fish animation i didn't succeed